# How to compare current time with a time variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, casting

I need to write a query in which I should compare current time with a variable which contains some time.

SQL Query:

```
select time >= curtime() from appointment;
```

Here `time` is the variable which has some time.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>='; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>='
```

I've already tried using time(now()) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `appointment.time` a `DATETIME` or similar data type, or is it a string?

It's probably best for your system's integrity if it's a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, not a string.

At any rate try this

```
select CAST(time AS DATETIME) >= CURTIME()
```

The way you've written your expression probably relies on some automatic type coercion, and it's better to make it explicit.

Comment: It's working but small edit to this `select CAST(time AS TIME) >= CURTIME()` beacuse I wanted only time.